# Intelij maven build fail after Intellij update

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project with 1.7 java. I attached the settings. Second picture is red, it is suggesting to update to java 1.8 but I can't it's a 1.7 project.
org/codehaus/classworlds/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Edit: downgraded Intellij to 2022.2.2 but it is still the same error

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use lower Maven version. You may manually set path to downloaded maven ("Maven home path" field).

Comment: Please show the full pom file... Also you can use JDK9+ and create code for Java 7... it's easier... why using such an old JDK version long long out of support etc..

Comment: Switched to 3.6, it was there on my machine, but still the same error

Comment: All maven org.codehaus.mojo stuff was modified last on 2014 in the pom files, it is some other setting need to be ticked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded to Intellij 2022.2.2. Still the same problem. Removed then added several mvn modules then it got solved